# Highest score in an international field hockey match

Tags: history, statistics, trivia, field-hockey

At the [1932 Summer Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_hockey_at_the_1932_Summer_Olympics), India defeated the USA with a score of 24-1.

Is this match the highest scoring match ever at international level?

Comment: An answer (now deleted) was posted with a claim of 55-0 win of Pakistan against Macao. AFAICT it was junior match. More details are [posted in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2433/2017/10/23).

Comment: **Moderator note**: please ensure that any answers to this question are supported with references to verifiable sources. Any answers which do not have sources are liable to be deleted.

Comment: India's 24-1 against the USA is the biggest margin win in Olympics but, there have been bigger margins at other events, especially in qualifiers. Important to know, at that time the Olympics were the only multination tournament as WC incepted in 1971 and CT in 1978.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061006103442AAvGyur) somebody states:

> In um Field Hockey it was 1994 when New Zealand pounded tiny [American Samoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Samoa) 36-1 in an Olympic qualifier. The Samaon goal came when a NZ defender put it in his own net, thus an own goal.

**I couldn't verify that.**

---

However, while looking for verification I did find this:

> Kookaburras [Australia] slaughter Samoa 26-0 in World Cup qualifier

See [here](http://www.couriermail.com.au/news/kookaburras-slaughter-samoa-26-0-in-world-cup-qualifier/story-e6freon6-1225766022899) and [here](http://www.heraldsun.com.au/news/aust-hockey-teams-flog-samoa/story-e6frf7jo-1225766067065).

I assume that this is [Samoa, the *nation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa).

---

And then I found [this](http://www.topofthecircle.com/OPoffensivesportsmanship.html).

> Argentina men 30, Dominican Republic 0
>
> Argentina women 25, Dominican Republic 0
>
> Chile men 25, Dominican Republic 0
>
> United States men 23, Dominican Republic 0
>
> Argentina U-21 women 21, Dominican Republic 0
>
> Chile women 20, Dominican Republic 0

---

Papua New Guinea (men and women) were beaten with monster scores by New Zealand and Australia, including

> **New Zealand  39 – 0   Papua New Guinea**

(See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Oceania_Cup).)

---

And Brazil, Bermuda and Peru have each lost to Argentina with 20 or more goals. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Women%27s_Pan_American_Cup), [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_Men%27s_Pan_American_Cup), [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Men%27s_Pan_American_Cup).

---

For other contenders, you might want to check each of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:International_field_hockey_competitions).